# Issues with integrating spring security saml 2.0 with adfs 2.0 as idp

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, saml-2.0

I am trying to integrate spring security saml 2.0 with adfs 2.0 as idp. But i am getting error saying- "Response doesn't have any valid assertion which would pass subject validation ".
Please find below saml tracer output.

```
`<samlp:Response ID="_7a5cd6ab-f2eb-4b24-b827-01b9852ca41d"
             Version="2.0"
             IssueInstant="2017-07-04T07:09:13.497Z"
             Destination="https://example.com/saml/SSO"
             Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified"
             InResponseTo="a4h23ag43aca1gh951g2c322ce22102"
             xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://example.com/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
<samlp:Status>
    <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
</samlp:Status>
<EncryptedAssertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
    <xenc:EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
                        xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <e:EncryptedKey xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                </e:EncryptionMethod>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <ds:X509Data xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                        <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                            <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US</ds:X509IssuerName>                               
                            <ds:X509SerialNumber>352932712240095357742.......</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                        </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                    </ds:X509Data>
                </KeyInfo>
                <e:CipherData>               
                    <e:CipherValue>oLddsOeYU6cozK4XsUdiCUM55C30nV3VZaaEv/M28hjj4zq3J0ylOBAzwiSa .....</e:CipherValue>
                </e:CipherData>
            </e:EncryptedKey>
        </KeyInfo>
        <xenc:CipherData>            
            <xenc:CipherValue>NUwiN6Xq2ibLA8NIlzZP5YK2W1hdGU9YeGjfvpqWiXTBGviKh/4uL6Fk8DF1 .....</xenc:CipherValue>
        </xenc:CipherData>
    </xenc:EncryptedData>
</EncryptedAssertion>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I do not think ADFS 2.0 supports the SAML-P protocol. There are mainly three federated sign-in protocols used by different identity providers (such as octa, adfs) and those are: WS-Federation, SAML-P and OpenID Connect/OAuth2. People often confuse protocol with token format. WS-Federation and SAML-P protocol uses both SAML format on the tokens thus people tend to mix the two protocols.

WS-Federation is a microsoft protocol used on ADFS. Newer versions of ADFS also supports SAML-P and OpenID Connect protocol. Also see [ADFS Deep-Dive: Comparing WS-Fed, SAML, and OAuth](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2014/11/02/adfs-deep-dive-comparing-ws-fed-saml-and-oauth/)

Comment: I think ADFS 2.0 supports SAML protocol. Issue might be with the adfs configuration. Please find the below link from where I took the reference and  trying to implement my own application . http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/chapter-idp-guide.html#d5e1748